# Export a DataSet[SomeClass] to geojson format in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, geojson

I have a DataSet of Feature in Spark. e.g. `DataSet[FeatureLine]`

I want to export the data to `geojson` format.
Also, the FeatureLine has a method toGeoJson which returns a String of the Class a GeoJson Formated string.

How can I use that to do something like that

```
ds.write.format("some.class.geojson.format").json(path)
```

ps. If I execute something like this

```
ds.write.json(path)
```

it returns a json object like that

```
{
    "geom": {
        "st_multiline_wkb": "AAAAAAUAAAABAAAAAAIAAABPQGICSncclw9AIZ65Xlr/KkBiFwYk3S8bQB+I4p+c6NlAYhiAnUlRg0AfSC0+/WvRQGIZx3mmtQtAHxHi3ocJdEBiHJd4VymzQB6cUmD15B1AYh286FM7EEAea48iR1KlQGIeDEm6XjVAHl6ygBps..... "},
    "data": {
        "Id": 2999,
        "StartTime": "2016-02-08T00:34:54.000+02:00",
        "EndTime": "2016-02-10T20:01:19.000+02:00",
        "Probable": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog post could help you:
https://mapr.com/blog/spark-data-source-api-extending-our-spark-sql-query-engine/

Or perhaps something simpler like:
https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/spark-workshop/tree/master/solutions/spark-mf-format

Comment: Was this what you meant?